# how file read write is handled in the node js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, file-io

Lets say I am writing and reading the same file in the node js. How the data integrity is handled ? Do we have locks or mutex in the node js ? or is it handled internally ?

```
fs.writeFile("test1", "Hey there! Really large data", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 


fs.readFile('test1', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Most likely the behaviour (esp of `fs.readFile`) will be undefined, or left up to the OS to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mutex or locks in node.js because it's single threaded.  The way I normally read a file and then write it is by something like this:

```
function copyFile(source, target){

    var done = function(err){
        console.log(err);
    };


    var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
    rd.on("error", function(err){
        done(err);
    });

    var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
    wr.on("error", function(err){
        done(err);
    };
    rd.pipe(wr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node file system documentation describes the operations as:

> File I/O is provided by simple wrappers around standard POSIX functions

There are no locks/mutexes in the [node file code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_file.cc) so it's the OS or the programmers responsibility to handle the consistency of the reads/writes.
Actually the use of locks or mutexes won't really help since node is single threaded and therefore the calls can not be called concurrently.

There is always an option, although not recommended, to use the synchronous version of the calls which will guarantee the reads/writes order.

Answer (score 0):

File locking is still an issue with node (As of version 11)

Suppose you are writing to a counter:

```
read counter file
counter +1
write counter to file
```

You need to place a lock (or wait for it) on the counter file, before you read it, to make sure you don't overwrite another asynchronous request.

it's amazing that file lock modules on npm, with millions of weekly downloads are unable to handle real concurrency or simply dosen't work.

See Alex Mills blog for a description: https://medium.com/@the1mills/a-better-mutex-for-node-js-4b4897fd9f11

He also provides a package to remedy that: https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex
Unfortunately it utilizes a TCP socket to operate, with all the complexity that entails.

I'm still looking for a working package using fcntl advisory file locking or another mechanism guaranteeing atomic locking. (symlink)